# Multivariate function inversion - Lagrange Inversion

Tags: inverse-function, lagrange-inversion

If I have a (bijective) scalar function $f : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^N$. Is it possible to obtain an inverse function $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^N $ such that $\vec{h}(f(\vec{x}))=\vec{x}$? A series expansion would suffice.

I believe that a multivariate extension of Lagrange Inversion Theorem (eg. see equation (1) in [this](https://hal.science/hal-00989632/file/lagrange.pdf) paper) should yield the answer but I cannot see how it would be possible to get a vector valued output.

Related but different questions:
[Inverse of multivariate function power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4651676/inverse-of-multivariate-function-power-series),
[Existence of an inverse of a multivariate function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4415484/existence-of-an-inverse-of-a-multivariate-function),
[Multivariate Lagrange inversion with powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237483/multivariate-lagrange-inversion-with-powers)

Comment: @TymaGaidash How would this yield a vector valued function $\vec{x} = \vec{h}(a)$?

Comment: There is no such bijection. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086974/continuous-bijection-from-mathbbrn-to-mathbbrm